# If $F,G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are injective functions then $F+G$ is injective.

Tags: calculus, functions

I wrote this proof (or rather the beginning of it), but it sounds a bit "illogical" to me, so I couldn't finish.

Let $F,G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be injective functions. Let $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Assume $(F+G)(a)=(F+G)(b)$, and prove that $a=b$.

$(F+G)(a) = F(a) + G(a) = x + y$ ($F, G$ injective so there exist one and only one element $a$ [respectively] in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $F(a) = x$ and $G(a) = y$)

$(F+G)(b) = F(b) + G(b) = c + d$ (Same as before)

Since $(F+G)(a)=(F+G)(b)$, we get that $x+y = c + d$

Since $F,G$ injective, and $x + c$ (here's my problem with this statement, since we don't REALLY know that $F(a) = x$ and $F(b) = c$, since we only know about the SUM of $F(a)+G(a)$, hence sounds a bit illogical to me

How do you continue from here? Sorry for my bad English, it's far from my native language! Also, sorry for the lack of formatting - I'm new to all of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the result you're trying to prove is even true to begin with?

Comment: The statement is false, take $F(x)=x$ and $G(x)=-x$.

Comment: I feel dumb that I didn't try to find a counterexample first. Thanks!

Comment: Take any injective function $f$ and define $g=-f$ and not that $g$ is injective but $f+g$ is far from injective